# Is it possible to implement a 3D map like Google Maps (or a 45° rotation, just enough to see buildings in different angles) on a Flutter app?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I'm working on an app that has in the center of it, a huge 2D map, but i want to make it 3D (or at least have a 45 degree rotation) to see buildings in details. Is it even possible?